# Why does a sleep between ActiveRecord#first calls change its behaviour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've inherited some code written in ruby 1.8.7 with Rails ~> 2.3.15 and it contains a test which looks something like this:

```rb
class Wibble < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Wibbles have integer primary keys and string names
end

def test
  create_two_wibbles
  w1 = Wibble.first
  sleep 2 # This sleep is necessary to
  w2 = Wibble.first

  w1.name = "Name for w1"
  w2.name = "Name for w2"

  w1.save

  w3 = Wibble.first

  assert(!w3.update_attributes(w2.attributes))
end
```

That comment next to the sleep line hasn't been cut off, it literally says `This sleep is necessary to`.  Without that sleep, this test fails - removing it changes the behaviour somehow beyond making it run 2 seconds faster. I've been digging through the file's history in our version control system, and the messages were uninformative. I also cannot contact the original author of this test to figure out what they were trying to do.

From my understanding, we're pulling the same record out of the database twice, editing it in two different ways, saving the first, and asserting that we can't then save the second. I suspect this is a test to make sure our database locks the table correctly, but surely if this were to fail our Wibbles would be fine, and ActiveRecord would be at fault. Nobody in the office can figure out why this test may have been necessary, nor what difference the sleep statement might make. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the version control history for clues?

Comment: @JakobW, yup. Unfortunately, the test was created in this state. There is no commit removing the end of that comment.

Comment: Have you asked the author?

Comment: No use of sleep in the above context. Because sleep halt the process until it expires time. Until we use threading concept there is no use of sleep in this snippet.

Comment: @Stefan, would if I could - I'm afraid they left the company before I joined, and I can't contact them.

Comment: @ymbirtt commit message or code added together with this doesn't lead anywhere?

Comment: @pramod, this is what I thought, too, however removing the sleep changes the behaviour of this test beyond making it run 2 seconds faster.

Comment: How is `create_two_wibbles` implemented?

Comment: What is the ruby version ?

Comment: @ymbirtt FUI, SQL doesn't make any guarantees when it comes to the order in which records are retrieved (unless, of course, the ORDER BY keyword is given). So Wibble.first is not always the first record

Comment: @ymbirrt Can you try Wibble.first(:order => :id) instead of Wibble.first

Comment: @JakobW, I'm afraid it's not that easy. No clues there either.

Comment: @Stefan, we have another related entity, let's call it a Squid. create_two_wibbles creates a pair of Wibbles, a pair of Squids, and adds two entries into a wibble_squid_link table which associates them with each other.

Comment: @pramod, we're using ruby 1.8.7 and rails ~> 2.3.15. The thought on Wibble.first not always being the first record is one I've also had, but adding an assert_equal w1,w2 does not change the behavior of the test. I'll try the ordering thing now.

Comment: @pramod, just tried it, no change to the test's behavior.

Comment: @ymbirtt Did you try by changing ruby version like 2.0

Comment: @ymbirtt Did you ever figure out the reason? Just curious.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil, nope, this is still open.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by Active Record caching and memoization stopping the second find from actually going to the DB and get fresh data.

In fact, try printing the object_id of each wibble; they might be the exact same memoized object. If that is the case, then the test kinda makes sense.

You could also do the same test in a controller action  and look at the verbose SQL logs from Rails; I'd expect the second find call to tell you it just used cached data and did not actually run any SQL query.